Sony SDK Connection Issue
I wanted to start using the Sony SDK in order to write an application to control my Sony A7 IV (which is a supported device).
I downloaded and built the demo application which came with that package but however I'm not able to connect to the camera (and press the shutter for example).
I was able to transfer images, so it shouldn't be a general connection issue.
When trying to connect, my camera is displayed like the following:
[1] ILCE-7M4 (xxxxxxxxxx)
Connect to camera with input number...
input>

When selecting the camera [1] the top-menu is visible. Afterwards I press Connect (Remote Control Mode) and then the remote menu is shown.
So far so good. When I now want to press the shutter nothing happens on the camera, and when I press (s) there is a message coming up like the following:
number - connected - model    - id
* 1    - false     - ILCE-7M4 - xxxxxxxxxx (the correct ID)

Did anyone observe the same issue with that demo application and has a solution?
Thanks!
Tried re-installing the camera driver and also transferring images instead of shoot which was successful.
